# DomainClass.getAll() not working correctly after merge

Tags: select, grails, grails-orm

I was trying to update a row on the database and noticed that once the row was updated, getAll stopped working correctly. All the records that were updated, started missing from getAll's result.

for instance, imagine you have a list of products [product1, product2, product3]. if I do something like product2.someProperty = 2 followed by a product2.merge(), product two will start missing from the list. So the result of Products.getAll() will be [product1, product3].

(Sorry if this is a noob question)

If I perform a Product.get(idOfUpdatedProduct), it will work. 
I've checked the database and the merge is updating the data correctly.
The problem seems to be on the GetAll() method.
findAll() presents the same behavior.

my code:

```
---action
def update() {
        Product product = productService.detail(params.id?.toLong())
        bindData(product, params)
        productService.updateProduct(product)
        redirect action: "show", params: [id: params.id]
}

---service
void updateProduct(product) {

        product.validate()
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder()
        product.errors.allErrors.each { str << "${it}" }

        if (!str.toString().isEmpty()) throw new Exception("Error: ${str.toString()}")

        product.merge(flush: true, failOnError: true)

    }
```

Comment: Comment, not answer because I'm not sure it will help: You may want to take a look at the merge documentation here http://docs.grails.org/3.3.2/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html and in particular the part saying that you must do something like product = product.merge().  I personally use save rather than merge but they are not the same thing so I'm guessing you have good reasons for using merge.

Comment: Even though it says I must do that, it shouldn't make any difference. 
I did some those changes to see if it helps, but it really does not change the result.

Comment: I believe the problem is the getAll method because the changes are applied to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

the result was actually being returned, but for some reason, it was placed in the middle of the list.

I solved it by sorting the list.